# Return different answers depending on which radio buttons are selected

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <h5>Does the PURPLE card have your number?</h5>
        <input type="radio" name="card1" value="A">yes<br>
        <input type="radio" name="card1" value="B">no<br>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h5>Does the GREEN card have your number?</h5>
        <input type="radio" name="card2" value="A">yes<br>
        <input type="radio" name="card2" value="B">no<br>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h5>Does the BLUE card have your number?</h5>
        <input type="radio" name="card3" value="A">yes<br>
        <input type="radio" name="card3" value="B">no<br>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h5>Does the PINK card have your number?</h5>
        <input type="radio" name="card4" value="A">yes<br>
        <input type="radio" name="card4" value="B">no<br>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h5>Does the RED card have your number?</h5>
        <input type="radio" name="card5" value="A">yes<br>
        <input type="radio" name="card5" value="B">no<br>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h5>Does the ORANGE card have your number?</h5>
        <input type="radio" name="card6" value="A">yes<br>
        <input type="radio" name="card6" value="B">no<br>
    </li>     
</ul>

<button onclick="returnScore()">View Results</button>
```

Using JavaScript, I am trying to get a different result returned based on which radio buttons are yes and which are no. For example, `yes no no no no no` would return answer 1. `yes yes no no no no` would return answer 2, etc., for 36 possible returns.

This problem comes from the card game here: http://www.counton.org/explorer/mathsmagic/realmystery/

Comment: It looks like you forgot to answer a question. Please read [ask] and [What not to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Answer (score 0):

A simple function is called when you click the button, it selects all elements using JavaScript and alerts both values.

I've added a form tag which contains all elements in your list so that I can select the inputs inside:

```
<script>
function showValues() {
    var inputs = document.getElementById("form").elements;
    var countYes = 0;
    var countNo = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        if (inputs[i].type == 'radio' && inputs[i].checked)
            if(inputs[i].value == "A") {
            countYes++;
            } else if(inputs[i].value == "B") {
            countNo++;
          }
    }
    alert("Number of Yes': " + countYes);
    alert("Number of No's: " + countNo);
}
</script>


<body>
<form id="form">
<ul>
    <li>
        <h5>Does the PURPLE card have your number?</h5>
        <input type="radio" name="card1" value="A">yes<br>
        <input type="radio" name="card1" value="B">no<br>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h5>Does the GREEN card have your number?</h5>
        <input type="radio" name="card2" value="A">yes<br>
        <input type="radio" name="card2" value="B">no<br>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h5>Does the BLUE card have your number?</h5>
        <input type="radio" name="card3" value="A">yes<br>
        <input type="radio" name="card3" value="B">no<br>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h5>Does the PINK card have your number?</h5>
        <input type="radio" name="card4" value="A">yes<br>
        <input type="radio" name="card4" value="B">no<br>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h5>Does the RED card have your number?</h5>
        <input type="radio" name="card5" value="A">yes<br>
        <input type="radio" name="card5" value="B">no<br>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h5>Does the ORANGE card have your number?</h5>
        <input type="radio" name="card6" value="A">yes<br>
        <input type="radio" name="card6" value="B">no<br>
    </li>     
</ul>
</form>
<input type="button" onclick="showValues();" value="click" />
```